# Need a string to print in fixed length in beanshell - Jmeter

Tags: python-2.7, jmeter, beanshell

I'm new to jmeter beanshell. I want to print the set of strings to view as table. For this, Is there any string operation in beanshell like .ljust() .rjust() in python. So that my job will be easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java String format, ljust():

```
 line = "one";
 log.info(line.format("%10s", new String[]{line}));
```

rjust():

```
 line = "one";
 log.info(line.format("%-10s", new String[]{line}));
```

Comment: ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: source Sourced file: /bin/log.bsh : Error in method invocation: Static method format( java.lang.String, java.lang.String ) not found in class'java.lang.String'

Comment: Thanks alot. "(line.format("%-10s", new String[]{line}));" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Using Beanshell for scripting is not very recommended](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), you should consider moving to JSR223 Test Elements and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language instead.

In Groovy you can truncate long strings to specified number of characters like:

```
'someString'[0..4]
//or
'someString'.take(5)
```

Both methods will return first 5 characters only

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Truncate String]

References:

- [Groovy SDK Enhancements](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#take(int))
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)